# Focusing of a cylindrical mirror in X-ray optics

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, reflection, x-rays, photonics

Focusing cylindrical mirror are sometimes used to squeeze a photon beam in one direction. They can be vertically focusing or horizontally focusing, and such mirrors are typically used in X-Ray optics like in the various synchrotron light sources across the world. I am trying to find a good reference that explains how this mathematically occurs, and for example the effect of the length of the cylinder on the final image, but I can't find any suitable reference. I find it hard to visualize. Any suggestions?

Please note: I really meant here cylindrical mirrors, not Kirkpatrick-Baez horizontally and vertically focusing mirrors, as those are actually elliptically shaped.

Comment: The length mainly affects intensity; a narrow ring does not gather much light. There are also toroidal mirrors (and toroidal gratings).